# Let $f(x) = 4x-2$ and $g(x)=x^3$, find the limit...

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = 4x-2$ and $g(x)=  x^3$ Please find the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to1}{g(f(x))} $$

Okay, so $f(x)$ would be $2$ and $g(x)$ would be $1$. How do you fit them in?

Sorry for my English!

Comment: Here's how to typeset your formulas: to get $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$, type `$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$`.  Put an extra `$` on both sides if you want it to look a little nicer, centered, and on its own line like $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$$  For more info, see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you like, you may change the title into a more general one, like "Limit of a composite function", so your post can be approached by users who have to deal with a similar situation.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x) = 4x-2$, $\;\;g(x)=x^3$, $\;\;\therefore \;\;g(f(x)) = (4x-2)^3$
$$\lim_{x \to 1} (4x-2)^3 = \lim_{x \to 1} (4(1)-2)^3 = 8$$

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can use this rule to find the limit of a composite function. Suppose that we have the composite function $g(f(x)) = (g\circ f)(x)$ and we want to evaluate  $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(f(x))$.

1. Set $ u = f(x)$.
2. Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x) = u_0$, (if it exists).
3. Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} g(f(x)) = \lim\limits_{u\to u_0} g(u) =\ell$ (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to 1} g(f(x))=\lim_{x\to 1} {f(x)}^3\\
\lim_{x\to 1} g(f(x))={(4x-2)}^3\\
\lim_{x\to 1} g(f(x))={(4-2)}^3\\
\lim_{x\to 1} g(f(x))=8
$$

Note that $g(f(x))$ is continous on $\mathbb{R}$ as both $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are. So the limit in $1$ is equivalent to calculating $g(f(1))$